# Nontrivial holomorphic vector bundle on $\mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: complex-geometry

Does there exist any nontrivial holomorphic vector bundle on $\mathbb{C}^n$?

I know $(1)$ Every line bundle on  $\mathbb{C}^n$ is trivial,  $(2)$ Every holomorphic vector bundle on $\mathbb{C}$ is trivial, (3) There exist a nontrivial line bundle on a contractible complex manifold, but I'm not sure if the above statement is true.

Comment: No, by Oka-Grauert.

Comment: What a fascinating theorem... Thanks a lot!